# mvn build is failing for tigase-web-ui-2.0 final

Tags: java, maven, tigase

We downloaded the pom.xml available at

https://projects.tigase.org/projects/sureim/repository/revisions/33b2a6f9cc27ced875f7e773f041ac381e2115b9

for

tigase-web-ui-2.0 final

and mvn build is failing

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project tigase-web-ui: Could not
>   resolve dependencies for project
>   tigase.sure.web:tigase-web-ui:war:2.0: Could not find artifact
>   tigase.sure.web:theme:jar:2.0.0 in gwt-mobile-webkit
>   (http://gwt-mobile-webkit.googlecode.com/svn/repo

) -> [Help 1]

Where do we find the relevant war / jar files.

Our mvn version is

```
Apache Maven 3.3.3 (7994120775791599e205a5524ec3e0dfe41d4a06; 2015-04-22T17:27:37+05:30)
Maven home: D:\Spacers\Gurupgm\Apache-maven-3.3.3\bin..
Java version: 1.8.0_45, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: D:\Spacers\Gurupgm\Java8\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "dos"
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try downloading the jar manually from the link [click](http://maven.tigase.org/tigase/sure/web/tigase-web-ui/2.0/)

After downloading install into maven repository by using the below command

> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=tigase.sure.web
>   -DartifactId=vomsProxyInitGUI -Dversion=2.0 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=/home/tigase-web-ui-2.0.jar

Comment: Thanks for your help. The pom.xml has references to

<groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>

<groupId>org.codehaus.gmaven</groupId>

and the 

http://www.codehaus.org/

webpage says "All Codehaus services have now been terminated." The webpage 

http://www.codehaus.org/mechanics/maven/

is not of much help. What changes should be made to the pom.xml